# How can i add my script from code behind to end of the file

Tags: java, javascript, code-behind, registerstartupscript

I have script for Google Analytics in my master page at the bottom of the page.
it is just below the  tag..... from the code behind i need to push some information to the google analytics. using the _gaq variable which there in that script.
sample: in my master page

i want to add my script after this script. i used RegisterStartupScript but the variable wich there in that .js is not loaded so that object throws an error undefined.
I dont have permission to move the google analytics script to above the  tag.
if i use RegisterClientScriptInclude then one more copy of  file i will load. that also not preferable. becouse google analytics shuld run after all page is loaded. so
How can i add my script from code behind to end of the file. after this script???

help me
Guru

Answer (score 0):

You can to added javascript file at the end of the tags. so it run after all tag initialization.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

/*
  // your codes

*/



<!--added your google analytic script here -->
<script src='js/ga.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works let me know if not..